# Net user command isn't working windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

My primary partition is D:\

I changed directory into D:\Users

Then I did

Net user /add useruser password

"The user or group account specified can not be found"

And right underneath that says "the user was successfully created but could not be added to the users local group"

Then I did

Net localgroup administrators useruser /add

"The command completed successfully"

But then I do 
Net user

And it says "user accounts for \ \

Administrator useruser guest"

What does \ \ mean

Why isn't my main account showing up when I do net user

My main account shows up when I do cd D:\users 
And then dir

That will list my main user account but it doesn't list the account I just tried to make.

Comment: are you working in recovery mode?

Comment: Type in `hostname` command and check what is the response. It seems like it should be empty if there is nothing after `\\`.

Answer (score 0):

Please start you cmd with admin rights before using net user.

The \\ usualy indicates the hostname of you Computer and it shouldnt be empty. My Computer says "useraccounts for \\John-PC".

To check the name of you computer just type "hostname" into the cmd and it show e.g "John-PC".